# How to make the login part in QuickFIX

Tags: c++, authentication, quickfix

How can I make the login part in QuickFIX in c++?
I found tons of tutorials and articles on how to do this on c# or java, but nothing on c++.

I have a server (acceptor), and a client (initiator). The username and password of the client are stored in the settings file, and are hardcoded in the server program.

From what I've read in the client I set the username and password in `fromAdmin()` and read and check the in the server in the `toAdmin()`, but how do I do that?

Here's what I've tried so far:

- cast the `message` to a `FIX44::Logon&` object using:

  ```
  FIX44::Logon& logon_message = dynamic_cast<FIX44::Logon&>(message);
  ```
- Set the Username and password to the logon object like this:

  ```
  if(session_settings.has("Username"))
  {
      FIX::Username username = session_settings.getString("Username");
      logon_message.set(username);
  }
  ```
- And send the message like this:

  ```
  FIX::Message messageToSend = logon_message;
  FIX::Session::sendToTarget(messageToSend);
  ```

But I get this error on the cast:

```
cannot dynamic_cast 'message' (of type 'class FIX::Message') to type 'struct FIX44::Logon&' (target is not pointer or reference to complete type)
```

What I've tried I got inspired from http://niki.code-karma.com/2011/01/quickfix-logon-support-for-username-password/comment-page-1/.

I'm still not clear on how to make the client and the server.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Possible mistakes:

1. I think you have `fromAdmin()`/`toAdmin()` backward.  `toAdmin()` is called on outgoing admin messages, `fromAdmin()` is called on incoming.  For the Initiator, you must set the fields within the `toAdmin()` callback.  Your Acceptor will check the user/pass in `fromAdmin()`.
2. Are you trying to `dynamic_cast` without first checking to see if it was a Logon message?  The `toAdmin()` callback handles *all* admin messages; the message could be a Heartbeat, Logon, Logout, etc.  That might explain your cast error.

As to what the code should look like, my C++ is rusty, but the basic pattern is this:

```
void YourMessageCracker::toAdmin( FIX::Message& message, const FIX::SessionID& sessionID)
{
    if (FIX::MsgType_Logon == message.getHeader().getField(FIX::FIELD::MsgType))
    {
        FIX44::Logon& logon_message = dynamic_cast<FIX44::Logon&>(message);
        logon_message.setField(FIX::Username("my_username"));
        logon_message.setField(FIX::Password("my_password"));
    }
}
```

From there, I think you can see how you'd write a similar `fromAdmin()` where you'd get the fields instead of setting them.

The above uses hard-coded user/pass, but you probably want to pull it from the config file.  I think your calls to `session_settings.getString(str)` are correct for that.

(Please forgive any coding errors.  I'm much more fluent in the Java/C# versions of the QF engine, though the basic principles are the same.)

I see that [your first web reference](http://niki.code-karma.com/2011/01/quickfix-logon-support-for-username-password/) uses the `FIELD_GET_REF` macro.  It may be better than `message.getHeader().getField()`, but I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've found this solution eventually, but it's great to know that I did the right thing.

Comment: Also, I is it wrong to read the username and password from standard input, line std::cin ? I've tried it and I can't get it to work.

Comment: Are you reading the user/pass before you start the initiator?  If yes, I don't see why it would be problem.  However, if you put the prompt in your toAdmin callback, then you'll probably hang your Init long enough to cause a timeout.